# How to select and count most frequent first value of each unique row?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would be grateful if you give me some tips on how to select most frequent first entries to a url with different id's.
So, for example, I have a table (`session_id`, `time`, `url`), and I want to know top 10 url's, where different users entered first when they used their browsers. Where should I start?

Comment: share sample data and output

Answer (score 1):

You could use an aggregated query to compute the total number of sessions for each url, and then you can use SQLServer `TOP` keyword to select the highest ranking records, like :

```
SELECT TOP 10 url, COUNT(session_id) total_sessions
FROM mytable
GROUP BY url
ORDER BY total_sessions DESC
```

If you want to count each session_id only once per url, you can use `COUNT(DISTINCT...)` :

```
SELECT TOP 10 url, COUNT(DISTINCT session_id) total_sessions
FROM mytable
GROUP BY url
ORDER BY total_sessions DESC
```

Comment: Ok, got it with DISTINCT. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 10 url, COUNT(session_id) total_sessions
FROM mytable
GROUP BY url
ORDER BY total_sessions DESC
```